# How to listen for iframe event sent by dispatchEvent

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe with code I cannot change that calls dispatchEvent on an event

```
 k = new MessageEvent("sendClipboard", {data: contenu});
...
document.dispatchEvent(k);
```

The parent of that frame needs to listen to that event and trigger a callback function

I have a sandbox here, with sample code of the 2 documents

http://plnkr.co/edit/WawxIOLTuR32ob1RCAtx

```
<iframe id="testFrame" src="frame.html"></iframe>
...
document.getElementById('testFrame').addEventListener("sendClipboard", callback, false);
```

NOTE: the frame code cannot be changed as it is provided, so I cannot use another target for the dispatchEvent (like using parent)